# If $\sum a_n$ is convergent and $a_n>0$, then $\sum (-1)^n a_n$ is convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series

> If $\sum a_n$ is convergent and $a_n>0$, then $\sum (-1)^n a_n$ is convergent.

So far I've tried convergence/divergence tests and also I tried to prove this using partial sums. But tests do not work because the latter series *includes negative terms*. Maybe the Alternating Series Test could have worked but "$a_n$ is decreasing" is not an initial condition. I know the proof will be very easy but I am stuck here. Could you provide me with a little **hint**?

Comment: The hint of Nicolò Ruggeri is the good one.

Comment: The sum of odd and even terms (separately) converge, so you can combine them together into another convergent sequence.

Comment: $\sum_{n \le N} a_{2n} \le \sum_{n \le 2N} a_{n}$ so $\sum_n a_{2n}$ converges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Theorem:** If $\sum |a_n|$ is convergent, then $\sum a_n$ is convergent.

**Proof:** Let $b_n=|a_n|+a_n \Rightarrow b_n=0 \: \: \mbox{or} \: \: b_n=2|a_n| \Rightarrow 0\le b_n \le 2|a_n| \stackrel{\mbox{DCT}}{\Rightarrow} \sum b_n$ is convergent. Therefore, $\sum b_n - |a_n|=\sum a_n$ is convergent.

This answers the question I asked.

**Remark:** Actually, the result is known as Absolute Convergence Test. I am learning the subject this semester. My apologies for asking the question early.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: any absolutely convergent series is convergent.Let me know if you want the full solution

Comment: That is another theorem to prove.

Comment: This would be the main way to do this, but if you don't know the theorem try with A.S hint, it works too!

Comment: Both has come to my mind but I was under the impression that there is one very easy answer.

Comment: Yes, as many times it's easy if you know the right theorem. Try looking on your book for mine, you'll study it for sure anyway!